# Iterating threw input elements that have almost similar names

Tags: vue.js, form-submit

I am working with vue.js and I have a form that has a lot of inputs, the number of inputs in the form is never the same because I have a couple of areas where the user can add inputs when they want to. the inputs that get added have the same name but differ from a counter.

I have built a method that  is going to submit the form and the inputs that are not changed in the form get pulled with this code:

```
    getFormValues (submitEvent) {
      debugger;
      this.Nr = submitEvent.target.elements.Nr.value
    }
```

but the problem here is that I don't know how to get all the values of inputs with the same name but with different id values so I can iterate threw then and build objects to post in the backend, I don't know how many of thus input is going to be added.

Comment: Share some code please.

Comment: what do you need, so you can understand the problem